# AngularJs from xml to json

Tags: android, xml, angularjs, mobile

I have a problem  to convert from xml to json the response of the web service with angularjs. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://demos.amitavroy.com/learningci/assets/js/xml2json.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in names">
        {{ x.theme }}
      </li>
    </ul>

    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("http://brickset.com/webservices/brickset.asmx/listThemes?")
      .success(function (response) {
     $scope.names = [];
    var x2js = new X2JS();
     var json = x2js.xml_str2json(response);
    $scope.names = json.ArrayOfThemeData.themeData;
    });
    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I can't see the list in the view
Can you help me please?

Comment: Then how can I use angularjs to create the list?

Comment: sorry for the question, but how can I control the datasource?

Comment: I want to build a mobile app withi ionic framework, and eccess to brickset webservice

Comment: But i tried to call the web service with jQuery Ajax, and its worked, I've created a list oh theme

Comment: So I can't use ionic framework?

Comment: but I haven't a server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the request using an XHR request because the server does not allow CORS requests. The service does not set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header so requests are being prevented.

This is probably intentional because the API documentation, [available here](http://brickset.com/tools/webservices/v1) requires that requests are authenticated by use of an API key or username and password combination.

If you had valid credentials to call the API, doing so using XHR directly with the service would mean exposing these in your client code, and that wouldn't be secure, which is probably the justification for the API not allowing XHR access.

Instead the API would have to be accessed using a proxy service which you set up. Your server would then query their API using your API key.

You can confirm that XHR requests are not permitted by trying to access the resource through [this CORS testing site](http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client#?client_method=GET&client_credentials=false&server_url=http%3A%2F%2Fbrickset.com%2Fwebservices%2Fbrickset.asmx%2FlistThemes&server_enable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=false&server_tabs=remote)

[See here](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) for how to handle CORS issues in Ionic.